# Yii, creating a listdata from a different file

Tags: php, yii, html-select

i want to make a ListData that will contain the content from a different file instead of DB, the file from where im going to get the data is going to be like:

```
1=>Usa
2=>France
3=>Italy
4=>Spain
5=>Venezuela
etc..
```

the porpuse of this is to make a DropdownList that will show the Country Items but its saving data is going to be just a id from the selected country..

i do know how to make the DropdownList, but im not sure about the ListData, im learning programming, sorry for asking such a ridiculous question.

please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ListData is used to convert the result of a query or a model into an array with a format like this one: 'ID'=>'DESCRIPTION'.
And that new array is what you need to populate a dropdownlist, checkboxlist, listbox...

If you already have a file with the list of values in that format, why don't you parse the file and create the array directly?

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of options for storing and reading data like this. If you want to stick to PHP, you would probably do something like this:

protected/data/listdata.php (or somewhere else):

```
<?php
return array(1 => 'USA', 2 => 'France', 3 => 'Italy', 4 => 'Spain'); // etc.

// Consider using zero-based indices. (0 => USA, 1 => France ...)
// Zero-based notation would look like this:
// return array('USA', 'France', 'Italy', 'Spain'); // etc.
?>
```

protected/views/index.php (or somewhere else):

```
<?php

$listdata = require_once('../data/listdata.php');
echo CHtml::dropDownList('Countries', 'USA', $listdata);

?>
```